# Firestore: Round-robin access to document in collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do something very simple, but not sure the best way to do this with Firestore.

I have an `ads` collection.

Each time an `ad` is accessed, I want to update the `accessed` property timestamp so I can just show the ad that hasn't been shown in the longest amount of time.

My security rules only allow users that carry a token with a payload of `admin:true` to create/modify `ads`.

So, from within the app, I can't update the timestamp each time an ad is accessed because the users aren't admins.

I looked at creating a function for this but realized that there is no `onGet` function that would allow me to do this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

I don't see anyway to allow a single property to be modified by any user.

What would be an appropriate way to do this with Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this either by creating a quite comprehensive rules validation where you make a check that all fields except `accessed` are unchanged. You can implement the admin role concept with [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) as described in [the answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54021237/7967164).

Checking that all fields except `accessed` are unchanged requires you to list and check all fields one by one.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /ads/{id} {
        allow read: if true; 
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true 
            || (request.resource.data.someField == resource.data.someField
        && request.resource.data.anotherField == resource.data.anotherField);
    }
  }
}
```

Another way, you could do it is to create a [callable cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) that works similar to [the Unix `touch` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(command)). You simply call it from your client for every time your read an ad and you can safely update the `accessed` field on the post within that function.

```js
export const touchAd = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const adId = data.id;
    return admin.firestore().collection('ads').doc(adId).update({
        accessed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }));
});
```